# how to disable checkbox in easyui-datagrid?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using a datagrid control for loading records. In that datagrid I have enabled the checkbox column using `checkbox:true` property. How can I disable a particular row's checkboxes in this datagrid?

```
$('#dg').datagrid({    
    url:'datagrid_data.json',
    columns:[[
        {field:'id',checkbox:true},
        {field:'name',title:'Name',width:100},
        {field:'price',title:'Price',width:100,align:'right'}
    ]]
});
```

Is there any datagrid property to disable checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the check boxes in easyui datagrid in  [this](http://www.cnblogs.com/ly7454/archive/2013/03/29/2989741.html)  way